# Java API to match multiple fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently I query ES for a single key value pair like this:

```
String query_key = "abc";
String query_val = "def";

searchRequestBuilder.setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(query_key, query_val)).execute().actionGet();
```

Now, instead of single key-value pair, I have the following key-value pair map: `Map<String,String> query_list`

How do I modify the same for this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [MuliMatchQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) or [Boolean Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to fulfill your requirement.

ex:-

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fields.entrySet()){
    boolQuery.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
```

Set this `boolQuery` in your `searchRequest` read the elasticsearch boolQueries and use one which fits for your requirement.

The Above example will perform the `AND` operation among the provided fields. the `field1` and `field2` must match. if you want to perform the `OR` operation then you should use `sould` query you have an option to set `minimum_should_match` in that you can specify the minimum fields should match.

Comment: @Arun - Perfect Answer. Thanks